# How do I make an AJAX block crawlable?

Tags: ajax

I have a block with a few tabs. When the user clicks the tab the content of that block get loaded.

Now I would like to make it crawlable by the search engines and at the same time I want to maintain the good user-experience.

I figured out a couple of alternative but each one has its own shortcomings. The approached that I could come up with.

- Use hashbangs and then use [this](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started). But hashbangs are not good and things of past now. Secondly it will make my content crawlable by only googlebot as yahoo and bing dont support this.
- Use GET PARAMETERIZED fallback incase when JavaScript doesn't work. This will work for all bots and also would be nice as it would work without JavaScript. But then this will create duplicates of my page as this block is only a very small section of my page and I have like around 5-6 tabs. So it means that many duplicates!

Doing this without AJAX is not an option as it would only increase the page load time as all these blocks have heavy media content in them!

Comment: Do it without ajax and then add ajax to it. progressive enhancement. win, win.

Comment: well then it will create duplicates of my page which is again lose lose in terms of SEO!

Comment: Not if the search engines don't process the javascript, which they won't do.

Comment: I think you are not clear with my question. what I mean to say is if use different pages to show my tab content to the search engines the rest of the content of the page gets duplicated which is not good for SEO. I hope you got my point now!

Comment: What is this media content? Do you want these media itself to be indexed or just the subject matter that it relates to? Is it possible to have the non-media content of the tab present on the page and only the media itself pulled in via AJAX?

Comment: @w3d what i mean by media content is images and videos along with a summary about that media item. and ya that kind of loading would be possible.I would love to have both the media itself and subject indexed but would my prime focus would be on the subject.

Comment: If you are loading that content via ajax, is that content available on a separate request URL? If so, you can get that indexed.

Answer (score 1):

[Google already tells you how to handle this.](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/)

Comment: I have already included that as part of my problem. Please read the question properly before posting an answer!

Comment: @VikasGulati Next time, use descriptive links and not just the word "this". While you may complain that the information only works with Google, they are the only search engine that will crawl your ajax enabled site, so your complaint is really with the other search engines and I don't think there is any other way around the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make anything, some search engine (like Google) now starts to crawl AJAX content.

Or otherwise, you have to do it the traditional way by assuming search engines don't runs Javascript. What they can see is just the static HTML codes.